# Setting a new label on all nodes takes too long in a huge graph

Tags: graph, neo4j

I'm working on a graph containing about 50 million nodes and 40 million relationships.
I need to update every node.
I'm trying to set a new label to these nodes, but it's taking too long.
The label applies to all 50 million nodes, so the operation never ends.
After some research, i found out that Neo4j treats this operation as a single transaction (i don't know if optimistic or not), keeping the changes uncommitted, until the end (which will never happen in this fashion).
I'm currently using Neo4j 2.1.4, which has a feature called "USING PERIODIC COMMIT" (already present in earlier versions). Unfortunately, this feature is coupled to the "LOAD CSV" feature, and not available to every cypher command.

The cypher is quite simple:

```
match n set n:Person;
```

I decided to use a workaround, and make some sort of block update, as follows:

```
match n
where not n:Person
with n
limit 500000
set n:node;
```

It's ugly, but i couldn't come up with a better solution yet.

Here are some of my confs:

```
== neo4j.properties =========
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=250M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=900M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=1300M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=1300M
keep_logical_logs=false
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=name_autocomplete,document
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=role
execution_guard_enabled=true
cache_type=weak
=============================

== neo4j-server.properties ==
org.neo4j.server.webserver.limit.executiontime=20000
org.neo4j.server.webserver.maxthreads=200
=============================
```

The hardware spec is:

```
RAM: 24GB
PROC: Intel(R) Xeon(R) X5650 @ 2.67GHz, 32 cores
HDD1: 1.2TB
```

In this environment, each block update of 500000 nodes took from 200 to 400 seconds. I think this is because every node satisfies the query at the start, but as the updates take place, more nodes need to be scanned to find the unlabeled ones (but again, it's a hunch).

So what's the best course of action whenever an operation needs to touch every node in the graph?

Any help towards a better solution to this will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried smaller batch of e.g. 50 000? That is the empirical value usually mentioned with size of neo4j transactions (10k - 50k depending on stuff you do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most performant way to achieve this is using the batch inserter API. You might use the following recipe:

1. take a look at `http://localhost:7474/webadmin` and note the "node count". In fact it's not the number of nodes it's more the highest node id in use - we'll need that later on.
2. make sure to cleanly shut down your graph database.
3. take a backup copy of your graph.db directory.
4. write a short piece of java/groovy/(whatever jvm language you prefer...) program that performs the following tasks

   1. open your `graph.db` folder using the [batch inserter api](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/2.1.4/batchinsert.html)
   2. in a loop from `0..<node count>` (from step above) check if the node with given id exists, if so grab its current labels and amend the list by the new label and use `setNodeLabels` to write it back.
   3. make sure you run `shutdown` with the batchinserter
5. start up your Neo4j instance again

Comment: I think this could really solve it, but it's the production database. I can't simply shut it down. If the only approach, when it comes to visit every node in the graph, is to shut the database down, then we are in real trouble here.

Thank you Stefan for the answer.